LSTM Masking with Attention Graph Execution Error
I've created an LSTM encoder - decoder for a Seq2Seq task but I am facing a problem that Attention layer is not working as expected even though my architecture is logically sound.
An example of one my data points is:
array([[-0.8439381 , -0.85880935, -0.67726948, ..., -0.86385393,
        -0.71588579, -1.0358093 ],
       [-0.87479022, -0.88740949, -0.72728084, ..., -0.76556575,
        -0.66317189, -0.98896579],
       [-0.9761566 , -0.92651054, -0.83835929, ..., -0.79129094,
        -0.83404377, -1.14996148],
       ...,
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ]])

The 0s represent masking and hence I do not want those to be included in LSTM calculations.
My encoder - decoder model looks like:
# Encoder
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(56, 840,))
masking_layer = keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=0.0)  
masked_input = masking_layer(encoder_inputs)
encoder_lstm = LSTM(256, return_sequences= True, return_state=True, dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.25)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder_lstm(masked_input)
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

# Decoder
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,))
decoder_embedding = Embedding(vocab_size, 512, mask_zero=True)(decoder_inputs)
decoder_lstm = LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.25)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_embedding, initial_state=encoder_states)

attention_layer = keras.layers.Attention()
attention_result = attention_layer([decoder_outputs, encoder_outputs], mask=)

# Combining attention output and decoder LSTM output
decoder_concat_input = keras.layers.concatenate([decoder_outputs, attention_result])

decoder_dense = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_concat_input)

# Define the model
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)

However, on calling model.fit, I get the following error:
Epoch 1/25
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[62], line 2
      1 # Train the model
----> 2 history = model.fit(
      3     [eeg_train, train_sequences], np.expand_dims(train_labels_sequences, -1),
      4     batch_size=128,
      5     epochs=25,  
      6     validation_data=([eeg_val, val_sequences], np.expand_dims(val_labels_sequences, -1)),
      7 )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:123, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    120     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    121     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    122     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 123     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    124 finally:
    125     del filtered_tb

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py:53, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     51 try:
     52   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 53   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     54                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     55 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     56   if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node functional_5_1/attention_7_1/sub defined at (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 17, in <module>

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 1043, in launch_instance

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 701, in start

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 195, in start

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603, in run_forever

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1909, in _run_once

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 534, in dispatch_queue

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 523, in process_one

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 429, in dispatch_shell

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 767, in execute_request

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 429, in do_execute

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 549, in run_cell

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3051, in run_cell

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3106, in _run_cell

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3311, in run_cell_async

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3493, in run_ast_nodes

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_1793/2682558571.py", line 2, in <module>

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 118, in error_handler

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 323, in fit

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 117, in one_step_on_iterator

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 105, in one_step_on_data

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 56, in train_step

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 118, in error_handler

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/layer.py", line 816, in __call__

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 118, in error_handler

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/ops/operation.py", line 42, in __call__

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 157, in error_handler

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/models/functional.py", line 188, in call

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/ops/function.py", line 153, in _run_through_graph

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/models/functional.py", line 572, in call

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 118, in error_handler

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/layer.py", line 816, in __call__

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 118, in error_handler

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/ops/operation.py", line 42, in __call__

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 157, in error_handler

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/attention/attention.py", line 227, in call

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/layers/attention/attention.py", line 175, in _apply_scores

required broadcastable shapes
     [[{{node functional_5_1/attention_7_1/sub}}]] [Op:__inference_one_step_on_iterator_15996]

How can I fix this? Attention layer was followed from official documentation (https://keras.io/api/layers/attention_layers/attention/)
